# Import both regular and solid icon with vue-fontawesome

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I'm trying to import both solid and regular icons

```js
import { 
    faFile
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

import {
    faFile
} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
```

But `faFile` cannot be defined again, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [rename the import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#rename_multiple_exports_during_import):

```js
import { 
  faFile as faFileSolid
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

import {
  faFile as faFileRegular
} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-fontawesome?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: We love you tony